# Can't keep data after a Signal/Slot transfer

Tags: c++, qt

so I'm trying to communicate data between two classes. 
The first class has a Signal which send a QString, the second class has the Slot which receive the QString. The problem is, the class receiving the QString is not keeping it. I can display it in the Slot but not elsewhere in the class. Here is my code :

**class1.h (Sender)**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void message(QString resolution);

private:

    GLWidget *widget;

    QString resolution;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**class2.h (Receiver)**

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

//
...
//
    float zoomWindow;

    QString resolution;


public slots:

    void reception(QString resolution);

};
```

**class1.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    resolution = "";

    widget = new GLWidget(NULL);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(message(QString)), widget, SLOT(reception(QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_clicked()
{
    resolution="0.2";
    emit message(resolution);
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_3_clicked()
{
    resolution="0.3";
    emit message(resolution);
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_2_clicked()
{
    resolution="0.5";
    emit message(resolution);
}
```

**class2.cpp**

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QGLWidget(parent)
{
    zoomWindow=0.5;
}

void GLWidget::reception(QString resolution){

   qDebug()<<resolution;               //DISPLAY CORRECTLY

   zoomWindow = resolution.toFloat(); //TRYING TO STOCK THE VALUE OF RESOLUTION                                                .                                       IN ZOOMWINDOW

   qDebug()<<zoomWindow;              //DISPLAY CORRECTLY

}
```

I didn't write all the code obviously, I only let the interesting parts.

So the value of zoomWindow is correct in the "reception" fonction, but if I try to display it in another fonction, it will be back to its original value.

I've tried to implement a fonction in the Reception slot to transfer the value but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: you haven't changed `resolution` member in your `GLWidget::reception(QString resolution)`. So, absolutely it will *be back to its original value* in other functions.

Comment: well, in case my first comment wasn't clear, just add `this->resolution=resolution;` to `void GLWidget::reception(QString resolution)`. This has nothing to do with Qt signals and slots.

Comment: Please provide a complete, concise test case that reproduces the issue. The multiple files are irrelevant - please minimize it all into a single `main.cpp` and remove everything that doesn't change the behavior. It doesn't even have to be a gui application, presumably.

Comment: One problem is, you never show your GLWidget. Is it intentional, that it is a separate window?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem. Maybe the problem is in a part of the code that you didn't share. But avoid using the parameter with the same name of a member of the class. The reading is confused.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the GLWidget to the main window programatically or using the form editor?

I've a similar code, I added the GLWidget using the form editor, and to access to the GLWidget from the main window i must use ui->glwidget-> ... .so maybe you have 2 GLWidget objects. I don't have any GLWidget variable created on the main window class.